# Clases en c++, modificar información de un archivo .txt

Tags: c++, archivo, clase

Hola buenos días a todos, espero que hayan o estén pasando un buen día. Tengo un problema con este código que estoy desarrollando en Dev c++ y es que no sé como podría modificar la información que se almacena en el archivo de texto, en específico la de la  varible int Costo_Prueba = 200, ya que al elegir la opción en el menú principal no sucede nada y me devuelve otra vez al menú principal.

Código completo:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <conio.h>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <locale.h>
 #include <wchar.h>
 using namespace std;

//Variables Globales//

int Costo_Prueba = 200;

//Fin Variables//

class Prueba{

private:
    
    char Nombre[30] , Apellido[30] ;
    long int Cedula;

public:
    
    Prueba ( char _Nombre[30]  , char _Apellido[30]  , long int _Cedula );
    void Menu();
    void Agregar_Persona();
    void Ver_Personas();
    void Registrar_Pago();
};

Prueba::Prueba( char _Nombre[30]  , char _Apellido[30]  , long int _Cedula ){

Nombre[30] = _Nombre[30];
Apellido[30] = _Apellido[30];
Cedula = _Cedula;

}

void Prueba::Menu(){

int Opcion;

do{

system( "cls" );
    
cout<<"\n\t--------------Menú Principal--------------"<<endl;

cout<<"\n\tOpción 1: Agregar persona a la prueba.";
cout<<"\n\tOpción 2: Ver personas en las pruebas.";
cout<<"\n\tOpción 3: Registrar pago."<<endl;
cout<<"\n\tOpción 4: Salir del programa.

cout<<"\n\t¿Qué opción eligirá? : "; cin >> Opcion ; cin.ignore();

  switch( Opcion )
  {
    
    case 1:
        
        system( "cls" );
        Agregar_Persona();
        
    break;
    
    case 2:
        
        system( "cls" );
        Ver_Personas();
        getch();
        
    break;
    
    case 3:
        
        system( "cls" );
        Registrar_Pago();
        
    break;

    case 4:

        system( "cls" );

    break;
    
    default:
        
        cout<<"\n\t¡Opción inválida!";
        
    break;
    
  }

 }while( Opcion != 4 );
}

void Prueba::Agregar_Persona( ){

ofstream Agregar;

Agregar.open( "Prueba basica.txt" , ios::out | ios::app );

cout<<"\n\t--------------Menú para agregar persona--------------"<<endl;

cout<<"\n\tIntroduzca el nombre de la persona: "; cin.getline( Nombre , 30 , '\n' );
cout<<"\n\tIntroduzca el apellido de la persona: "; cin.getline( Apellido , 30 , '\n' 
);
cout<<"\n\tCédula: "; cin >> Cedula; cin.ignore();

system( "cls" );

cout<<"\n\t--------------Datos de la persona--------------"<<endl;

cout<<"\n\t Nombre: " << Nombre;
cout<<"\n\t Apellido: " << Apellido;
cout<<"\n\t Cedula: " << Cedula;
cout<<"\n\t Deuda: " << Costo_Prueba; 

Agregar<<Nombre<<" "<<Apellido<<" "<<Costo_Prueba<<" "<<Cedula<<endl;

}
```

El problema es en esta parte del código, en Registrar_Pago, ya que cuando yo
introduzco la cédula para buscar a la persona guardada en el archivo llamado Prueba
basica.txt que se crea al yo añadir una nueva persona sencillamente no ocurre nada y
me devuelve otra vez al menú principal del programa.

```
void Prueba::Registrar_Pago(){

ifstream Ver;
ofstream Auxiliar;

Ver.open( "Prueba basica.txt" , ios::in );
Auxiliar.open( "Auxiliar.txt" , ios::out );

char Nombre_Aux[30] , Apellido_Aux[30];
long int Cedula_Aux , Ced;
int CostoPrueba_Aux , Pago , resultado ;
bool Encontrar = false;

CostoPrueba_Aux = Costo_Prueba;

cout<<"\n\tIntroduzca su cédula : "; cin>>Cedula_Aux; cin.ignore();

if( Ver.is_open()){
    
    Ver >> Nombre_Aux[30];
    
    while( !Ver.eof() && !Encontrar ){
        
        Ver >> Apellido_Aux[30];
        Ver >> Costo_Prueba;
        Ver >> Ced;
        
        if ( Ced == Cedula_Aux ){
            
            cout<<"\n\tIntroduzca el pago : "; cin>>Pago;
            
            resultado = CostoPrueba_Aux - Pago;
            
            Auxiliar<<Nombre_Aux[30]<<" "<<Apellido_Aux[30]<<" "<<" "<<resultado<<" " 
  <<Ced<<endl;
            
        }else {
            
            Auxiliar<<Nombre_Aux[30]<<" "<<Apellido_Aux[30]<<" "<<" " 
  <<CostoPrueba_Aux<<" "<<Ced<<endl;
            
        }
        
        Ver >> Nombre_Aux[30];
    }
    
    Ver.close();
    Auxiliar.close();
    
}else
    
    cout<<"\n\t¡Cédula no encontrada!."<<endl;
    remove ( "Prueba basica.txt");
    rename ( "Auxiliar.txt" , "Prueba basica.txt" );
    
    
}

int main(){

setlocale( LC_ALL , "spanish" );
char Nombre2[30] , Apellido2[30];
long int Cedula2;
Prueba Llamar( Nombre2 , Apellido2 , Cedula2 );

Llamar.Menu();

return 0;
}

Corté varias partes del código, y por eso le faltan algunas partes.
```

Comment: Hola. Recomiendo que uses std::string en vez de arreglos de char. Eso podría simplificar bastante el código, y eliminar algunos problemas relacionados con cómo se están manejando los strings actualmente.